# Why when I insert values to SQLite database, these are set to null?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I try to create a todo list app. 
I run the app and insert values via EditText in SQLite database, but when I open it, the values are set to null. 
What am I doing wrong?

These are the activities:

1.Database

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "taskdb";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String TABLE_TASKS = "tasks";
    private static final String KEY_TASK_ID = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_TASK_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_TASK_DATE = "date";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TASKS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TASKS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                KEY_TASK_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_TASK_DATE + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TASKS_TABLE);}

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tasks" + TABLE_TASKS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addTask(Task task) {
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_TASK_NAME, task.getTaskName());
        values.put(KEY_TASK_DATE, task.getTaskDate());

        db.insert(TABLE_TASKS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<Task> getAllTasks() {
        String[] columns = {
                KEY_TASK_ID,
                KEY_TASK_NAME,
                KEY_TASK_DATE};
        ArrayList<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TASKS,
                columns,
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
             do {
                 Task task = new Task(
                         parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                         cursor.getString(1),
                         cursor.getString(2));
                taskList.add(task);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return taskList;
    }
}
```

2.The activity where I have the EditText

AddTaskActivity.java

```
public class AddTaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView addNewTask, setStartTime, setEndTime;
    EditText addTaskName;
    TimePicker timePicker1, timePicker2;
    int hour1, minute1;
    int hour2, minute2;
    String theNewTask;
    Button addTaskButton;
    TasksListActivity tla;
    DatabaseHandler dth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_task);
        dth = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        addNewTask = findViewById(R.id.addNewTask);
        setStartTime = findViewById(R.id.setStartTime);
        setEndTime = findViewById(R.id.setEndTime);
        addTaskName = findViewById(R.id.addTaskName);
        timePicker1 = findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        timePicker2 = findViewById(R.id.timePicker2);
        addTaskButton = findViewById(R.id.addTaskButton);

        addTaskButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String name = addTaskName.getText().toString();
                        Task task = new Task();
                        task.setTaskName(name);
                        task.setTaskDate("date");

                        dth.addTask(task);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(AddTaskActivity.this, TasksListActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

3.Object class

Task.java

```
public class Task  {
    String tTaskName, tTaskDate;
    int ID;
    public Task(int ID, String tTaskName, String tTaskDate){
        this.tTaskName = tTaskName;
        this.tTaskDate = tTaskDate;
        this.ID =ID;
    }
    public Task(){}

    // Getters and setters for all attributes
}
```

4.Adapter for RecyclerView

TaskAdapter.java

```
public class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Task> tasksList;
    private Context mContext;

    public TaskAdapter(ArrayList<Task> tasksList, Context mContext){
        this.tasksList = tasksList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.task_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Task stringTask = tasksList.get(position);
        holder.taskText.setText(stringTask.getTaskName());
        holder.dateText.setText(stringTask.getTaskDate());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tasksList == null ? 0:tasksList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        View view1;
        TextView taskText, dateText;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            view1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view1);
            taskText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.taskTextView);
            dateText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
            relativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        }
    }
}
```

5.Activity where the data should be displayed

TasksListActivity.java

```
public class TasksListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    TaskAdapter taskAdapter;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<Task> tasksList;
    DatabaseHandler dth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks_list);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.taskListItem:
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(TasksListActivity.this, TasksListActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        break;
                    case R.id.addTasks:
                        Intent intent5 = new Intent(TasksListActivity.this, AddTaskActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent5);
                        break;
                    case R.id.noteListItem:
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(TasksListActivity.this, NotesListActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        tasksList = new ArrayList<>();
        taskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(tasksList, TasksListActivity.this);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        dth = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        getDataFromSQLite();

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(taskAdapter);
    }

    private void getDataFromSQLite() {
        // AsyncTask is used that SQLite operation not blocks the UI Thread.
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                tasksList.clear();
                tasksList.addAll(dth.getAllTasks());

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issue is with the **Task** class in that you are not using the passed values for the set methods to set the object's values, rather you are using the unset values to set themself.

Your **Task.java** should be (see comments) :-

```
public class Task  {
    String tTaskName, tTaskDate;
    int ID;
    public Task(int ID, String tTaskName, String tTaskDate){
        this.tTaskName = tTaskName;
        this.tTaskDate = tTaskDate;
        this.ID =ID;
    }
    public Task(){}
    public void setID(int i){
        //this.ID = ID; //<<<<<<<<<<WRONG will set to null
        this.ID = i; //<<<<<<<<<<Correct sets the value to the value that was passed (albeit not contributing to the problem)
    }
    public int getID(){
        return ID;
    }
    public void setTaskName(String name){
        //this.tTaskName = tTaskName; //<<<<<<<<<<WRONG will set to null
        this.tTaskName = name; //<<<<<<<<<<Correct sets the value to the value that was passed
    }
    public String getTaskName(){
        return tTaskName;
    }
    public void setTaskDate(String the_date){
        //this.tTaskDate = tTaskDate; //<<<<<<<<<<WRONG will set to null
        this.tTaskDate = the_date; //<<<<<<<<<<Correct sets the value to the value that was passed
    }
    public String getTaskDate(){
        return tTaskDate;
    }
}
```

Additionally your code would not compile due to **KEY_ID** rather than **KEY_TASK_ID** being coded as per :-

```
//String CREATE_TASKS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TASKS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + //<<<<<<<<<<ERROR 1
        String CREATE_TASKS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TASKS + "(" + KEY_TASK_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                KEY_TASK_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_TASK_DATE + " TEXT" + ")";
```

- The commented out line being the line in error, as per the comment.

The following was used to test the above (as an example of debugging using the system log (this was enough to find the issue)) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHandler mDBHndlr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDBHndlr = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        Task tasktoadd = new Task();
        tasktoadd.setTaskName("Test001");
        tasktoadd.setTaskDate("2019-01-01");
        mDBHndlr.addTask(tasktoadd);
        ArrayList<Task> tasklist = mDBHndlr.getAllTasks();
        for (Task task: tasklist) {
            Log.d("MYTASKTEST","Task name is " + task.getTaskName() + " Date is " + task.getTaskDate());
        }
    }
}
```

The output, in the log, when the changes were applied :-

```
2019-05-14 06:14:52.458 5758-5758/? D/MYTASKTEST: Task name is Test001 Date is 2019-01-01
```

(instead of `2019-05-14 06:14:52.458 5758-5758/? D/MYTASKTEST: Task name is null Date is null`)